# Sum of price for each type of item

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm new here and I dont know how to create table like other users do, so please bear with me. So i have two tables. The first table lists 3 types of item. The second table lists the types of the items and the price sold for each item. So for example,

Table 1 has Product A, B, C, Name of Origin, Date Ordered

Table 2 has

```
        Product A @ $50
        Product A @ $25
        Product A @ $10
        Product A @ $30
        Product B @ $10
        Product B @ $20
        Product C @ $5
        Product C @ $10
        Product C @ $25
```

Now, i want to calculate the sum of product sold for each product type. That means i should have the output product A of 92.5, product B of 15, product C of 20. The thing is, my syntax only gives the same output for each product so for product A,B,C the output is 92.5. How do I fix it so it gives the proper result? Thanks!

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`, `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Give the Query, you already tried

Comment: You can use [SQLFiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com) to practice. Then you can edit your question and include a link to the fiddle you've created so others can help you. If you need help with syntax for e.g. a `CREATE TABLE` statement you can check the online version of the [Oracle SQL Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/toc.htm).

Comment: How is sum of `Product A = 92.5`? As far as i can see, it should be `50+25+10+30 = 115` and same for other products.

Comment: See an example: [SQL SUM() function with group by](https://www.w3resource.com/sql/aggregate-functions/sum-with-group-by.php)

Answer (score 2):

Since you want the **SUM** for **EACH** product type (i.e. A, B, and C). You need to use:

1. the aggregate function **SUM()**: returns the sum of a numeric column.
2. **INNER JOIN** keyword: to join column price with product name of the two different tables together, based on matching values.
3. **GROUP BY** statement: group the result-set by one or more columns.

Tip: if you see the keywords, *for each X*, that almost always means *GROUP BY X*.

I cannot see the actual design of your tables, but this should be enough to solve your issue:

```
SELECT p.producttype, SUM(t.price) AS totalprice FROM Table1 AS p
JOIN Table2 as t
ON p.productid = t.productid
GROUP BY p.producttype
```

I hope this helps.